# select first and last record of each group horizontally

Tags: sql, postgresql, eloquent

I have a table like
[image]

i want to select first and last record of every group by facility_id and created_at horizontally 
need to output like . i can do it vertically but need horizontally 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is much simpler using window functions and `select distinct`:

```
select distinct facility_id, name,
       first_value(value) over (partition by facility_id, name order by created_at asc) as first_value,
       min(created_at) as first_created_at,
       first_value(value) over (partition by facility_id, name order by created_at desc) as last_value,
       max(created_at) as last_created_at
from t;
```

No subqueries.  No joins.

You can also use arrays to accomplish the same functionality, using `group by`.  It is a shame that SQL Server doesn't directly support `first_value()` as a window function.

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: Does query work on AWS Athena/Presto? Looks like it is asking for the Facility_id, name and created_at in the group by clause!

Comment: my limited experience with a _similar_ query in Trino (ex PrestoSQL) is that the `DISTINCT` is calculated before, not after the windows functions like `FIRST_VALUE()`. But this is not the only reason why I don't think this query works. What are the `MAX()` supposed to be calculated on?

Answer (score 4):

```
with CTE as (
  select 
  *
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by facility_id,name order by created_at asc ) ascrnk
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by facility_id,name order by created_at desc ) desrnk
  from TestTable
)
select T1.facility_id,T1.name,
  T1.value as "First_value",
  T1.created_at as "First created_at",
  T2.value as "Last_value",
  T2.created_at as "Last created_at"  
from (
  select * from cte
  where ascrnk = 1
) T1
left join (
  select * from cte
  where desrnk = 1 
) T2 on T1.facility_id = T2.facility_id and T1.name = T2.name
```

---

**Result:**

```
| facility_id | name | First_value |     First created_at | Last_value |      Last created_at |
|-------------|------|-------------|----------------------|------------|----------------------|
|        2011 |    A |         200 | 2015-05-30T11:50:17Z |        300 | 2017-05-30T11:50:17Z |
|        2012 |    B |         124 | 2015-05-30T11:50:17Z |        195 | 2017-05-30T11:50:17Z |
|        2013 |    C |         231 | 2015-05-30T11:50:17Z |        275 | 2017-06-30T11:50:17Z |
|        2014 |    D |         279 | 2017-06-30T11:50:17Z |        263 | 2018-06-30T11:50:17Z |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/70a81/22/0)

Comment: I fix it @Masumbillah

Comment: This is a fine answer, but it is so much more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Just done in such an intelligent way... Thanks!